# how to mock a function in pytest monkeypatch?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I am trying to mock a simple function but I get an AttributeError and have no clue on how to fix it.

```
def my_function():
    return "original"

def mock_my_function():
    return "mocked"

def test_my_function(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(__name__, 'my_function', mock_my_function)
    assert my_function() == "mocked"
```

What should I put in __name__'s place to make it work?

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback and [mre]. What is `monkeypatch`? Are you sure it has `setattr` method or are you confusing it with [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) function?

Comment: @vmp Try with `monkeypatch.setattr(__name__ + 'my_function', mock_my_function)`, but I don't know `monkeypatch`. If you want I can write a **tested** answer to your question that use the `unittest.mock.patch()` function.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych it is already reproducible. Just needs to run pytest at it will reproduce.

Comment: @frankfalse I'm actually reading a book on pytest and wanted to do a simpler example because the book's code example has many files. The answer I accepted solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put your function that you want to test in a different file so that it can behave as a module.

file with functions you want to test (named original_code.py);

```py
def my_function():
    return "original"
```

file with test (named test_set.py):

```py
import pytest
import original_code

def test_my_function(monkeypatch):
    
    def mock_my_function():
        return "mocked"
    monkeypatch.setattr(original_code, 'my_function', mock_my_function)
    assert original_code.my_function() == "mocked"
```

structure of the files

```
|_ original_code.py
|_ test_set.py
```

this should mock the function named "my_function" with "mock_my_function" defined inside the test

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it with `setitem()`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

def my_function():
    return "original"

def mock_my_function():
    return "mocked"

def test_my_function(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setitem(globals(), 'my_function', mock_my_function)
    assert my_function() == "mocked"
```